# Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application with GMaps JS API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've been banging my head on the wall after going through the documentation on this several times! I can't seem to get past the API error to get the map to appear on my site.

I am getting the following error message from the web page where I want the map to be displayed:

> Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. The provided key is not a valid Google API Key, or it is not authorized for the Google Maps Javascript API v3 on this site. If you are the owner of this application, you can learn about obtaining a valid key here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Obtaining_Key

I have (several times now) gone into my account and:

1. enabled the Maps v3 API service
2. generated a new API key
3. added my allowed referrers to the key. (both www.domain.com and domain.com URLs)

I have the following script added to the head of the web page:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;key=MY_API_KEY_HERE" type="text/JavaScript" language="JavaScript"></script>
```

And I have the following JavaScript function that executes when a link is clicked on the page:

```
alert("viewMap()");
var map = new GMap3(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
var geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();

var address = "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain  View";
alert("Calling getLatLng ...");
geocoder.getLatLng(address, function(point) {
    var latitude = point.y;
    var longitude = point.x;  

    // do something with the lat lng
    alert("Lat:"+latitude+" - Lng:"+longitude);
});
```

The initial `viewMap()` alert is displayed and then is followed by the 'Google has disabled use...' error message.

The error console is also showing 'GMap3 is not defined'.

Can anyone please assist with showing me the errors of my ways?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just change the GMap3 line to:

```
var myOptions = {zoom: 5,mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),myOptions);
```

Here's a more complete example of using `navigator.geolocation` instead of the `GClientGeocoder`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<style>
#map_canvas {width:300px;height:300px;display:block;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<button onclick="begin();">Click</button>
</body>
<script>
function begin(){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(loadmap,noloc);
}

function noloc(){ alert('Since this is a location based tool, please reload and share your location');}

function loadmap(position){

    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 5,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),myOptions);
    var latitude=position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude=position.coords.longitude;
        //do something with the lat lng
    var usrll=new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);
    map.setCenter(usrll);
    var usrmarker = new google.maps.Marker({position: usrll,map: map});

}   
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: No.  I just added that and am still getting the same results/error.

Comment: Thanks.  I am going to get this working with v2 and then work on migrating to v3 ...

Answer (score 0):

Several issues, the most serious of which is loading the Version 3 API with your `<script>` tag and then using Version 2 code like `GClientGeocoder`. And `GMap3` does not exist at all in either version.

Converting a Version 2 map to Version 3 is not as simple as loading the Version 3 API. It needs to be rewritten from scratch (and that's outside the scope of SO).

You don't say what referrers you are using, but you need to be explicit in your use of wildcards: `www.domain.com/*`, `domain.com/*`

I would suggest changing `GMap3` to `GMap2`, and ensure that you load the Version 2 API (specifying your Console key in the relevant `<script>` tag). And then set about re-writing for Version 3.

Comment: Ok...  I made some changes and seem to be closer...

1) I changed to load the v2 API.
2) Changed my javascript to create a GMap2 object
3) Confirmed that my referrers included the wildcards
4) Turned off my v3 service and enabled the v2 service

Comment: I now get to my second alert which shows that it is attempting to get the Lat/Lng ...

I then get the following error dialog:

Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. The provided key is not a valid Google API Key, or it is not authorized for the Google Maps Javascript API v2 on this site. If you are the owner of this application, you can learn about obtaining a valid key here: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/introduction.html#Obtaining_Key

Comment: @user1496322 There's no longer enough information. Need to know: the *exact* url of the map; *exactly* what you have in your referrers; *exactly* what your `<script>` tag is now. I suggest you update the question.

Comment: I changed my key to be the 'Any referrers allowed' one and it all seems to be working now.  

Thanks for your help!